# How can I boot Rails 3 in a daemonized ruby script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, daemon

I am pulling email via pop into my Rails 3 application so i have a file called dropbox_receiver.rb in the rails lib directory.

This pulls in all email and calls DropBox.receive(email)

I can run this using rails/runner but when i run it from the daemon_controller.rb file i get the error

```
initialized constant Object::DropBox
```

How do i boot rails 3 in this script ?

Also how do i log properly from this script to my production.log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this at the top of your script:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = ARGV.first || ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development'               
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../../config/environment"
```

That's for a script in app/controllers. You'll need to adjust the path to config/environment if your daemon is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you're probably going to run into the issue of open files as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711603/ruby-daemons-causing-activerecord-logger-ioerror).